# Thousands of pam_unix log entries in logwatch

Tags: cron, log

My logwatch reports, within the `CRON` section, contain thousands of entries like those below. How can I either reduce the number of log entries OR have `logwatch` ignore them?

```
Jan 30 18:49:01 ota3 CRON[14054]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user zzz by (uid=0)

Jan 30 18:49:03 ota3 CRON[13055]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root

Jan 30 18:49:08 ota3 CRON[14054]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user zzz

Jan 30 18:50:01 ota3 CRON[14108]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user zzzr by (uid=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `/etc/pam.d` directory.
Open the file `common-session-noninteractive` in an editor.
Look for the following line:

```
session required pam_unix.so
```

Above this line, add the following:

```
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in cron quiet use_uid
```

Save the file and exit.
Restart crond using something like `service cron restart` or `/etc/init.d/cron restart`.

Source: http://languor.us/cron-pam-unix-cron-session-session-opened-closed-user-root-uid0