# Removing cron spam from /var/log/auth.log on 18.04 Server

Tags: cron

Requesting suggestions, tips, hints for ridding myself of these annoying cron logs.

```
May 14 01:30:01 localhost CRON[18435]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user tuptime 
May 14 01:35:01 localhost CRON[20737]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user tuptime by (uid=0) 
May 14 01:35:01 localhost CRON[20737]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user tuptime
```

Background - I have a program called tuptime installed on the server to give me uptime stats. I experimented with removing the program (very unsuccessfully I might add) and am now plagued with these annoying cron notifications whenever checking /var/log/auth.log.

Thanks all. Just assume I'm a two-bit novice if replying.

Comment: So the question is about "how to remove tuptime" or "how to filter logs"?

Comment: I think that the solution was already posted here: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139323/dont-log-cron-events-in-auth-log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139323/dont-log-cron-events-in-auth-log)

Comment: Hi George - it was kind of a two fold question. I am also interested in understanding how to completely remove tuptime, including all of the uptime stats which go back to December 2018 in my case. I'm hoping to have a fresh counter when I transfer the system to totally new hardware in the coming months.

Comment: Nope, actually this is the sole reason for this misbehavior: https://languor.us/cron-pam-unix-cron-session-session-opened-closed-user-root-uid0 as stated here: https://askubuntu.com/a/280255/366528

Answer (score 1):

You will need to examine all the cron locations: `/etc/cron.d/` and `/etc/crontab` and `crontab -l` and `/etc/pam.d/cron` for that user. There will be a line in one of those that triggers this.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. That got me on the right track as far as removing those annoying cron logs. I found 'tuptime' inside /etc/cron.d/ and changed the cron schedule from every five minutes to once daily. Already did the trick. Thanks man.

Comment: @vellofrell2592 That being the case please click the check mark next to Rinzwind's answer to let others know it is the correct answer. Thanks,